# Is it possible to set naviagtion uri for BackTile click

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have developed wp8 app,

I am updating my app tile at some scenarios,

here the code i have used for update my tile

```
 ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();

            StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
            {
                BackgroundImage = new Uri(@"/ApplicationTile.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                Count = NotificationCount,
                BackTitle = offers.data.info[0].offer_title,
                BackContent = offers.data.info[0].location_area,

            };

            TileToFind.Update(NewTileData);
```

Here my doubt is, is it possible to set navigation uri for the BackTile, like as i give the navigation uri in my toast message here

```
 Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellToast toast = new Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellToast();
            toast.Content = "@" + offers.data.info[0].location_area;
            toast.Title = offers.data.info[0].offer_title;
            toast.NavigationUri = new Uri("/LocationDealsPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            toast.Show();
```

I need to navigate to different pages while click the back tile and front tile.

Anybody please let me know, is that possible are not, if possible please let me know how.

If not possible is there any other way to do this.

Thank you.

Noorul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set a different URI to navigate to when the user taps a tile when the back is displayed.

If you need to navigate to different parts of the app you could use multiple tiles.

Alternatively, if you're remotely updating the back of the tile when there is new information available and you want to do a different action when launching the app and there is new information (e.g. go to straight to that new item rather than the main page) you could do this check when the app is opened. To avoid having to make a[n extra] network request on app start up, you could use a background agent to regularly pull down the latest data (including a flag to detect if there is a new item) so it's there when the app is launched.

Comment: Thanks Matt, your answer help to me.